# .htaccess rules - How to redirect incoming "/login.php" url request to "index.php?do=login"?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I want to redirect all incoming url requests to index.php via `.htaccess`

Example:

```
/johngroup -> /index.php?do=johngroup
/addmem    -> /index.php?do=addmem
/autoshare -> /index.php?do=autoshare
/spamwall  -> /index.php?do=spamwall
```

`index.php` will handle all requests.

Following code is not working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([A-Za-z0-9_-.]*).php?    do=(.*)
   RewriteRule .* /%1.php?do=%2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your example is not clear. What URLs are you wanting to redirect from/to?   "I want to rewrite/redirect" - note that "rewrite" and "redirect" are strictly two different things. Which URL do you want to see in the browser's address bar?

Comment: like if user request for `http://example.com/test` it will redirect to `http://example.com/index.php?do=test`

Comment: yes abhushek sir, 'http://example.com/test.php' to http://example.com/index.php?do=test

Comment: That is potentially quite different from what Abhishek is suggesting. Is `/test.php` a valid PHP file? Or should it simply match URLs that end `.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On                                
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L]                    # 1
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ index.php?do=$1 [L]      # 2
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?do=$1             # 3
```

Explanation:

1. If urls starts with `/index.php`, stop processing. Otherwise proceed to next rule.
2. If url format is `/x.php`, rewrite to `/index.php?do=x` and stop processing further. Otherwise proceed to next rule.
3. Convert any url e.g `/test`, to `/index.php?do=test`.

You can also test and tweak htaccess rules using these sites:

- [Htaccess Tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)
- [Rewrite Rule Tester](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/)

Answer (score 0):

> `example.com/test.php` to `example.com/index.php?do=test`

Try the following in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(\w+)\.php$ index.php?do=$1 [L]
```

The above will *internally rewrite* `/test.php` to `/index.php?do=test` (ie. `/test.php` remains in the browsers address bar), regardless of whether `test.php` exists as a physical file on the filesystem. Basically, any file that has a `.php` file extension. The `RewriteCond` directive prevents a rewrite loop.

If you only need to rewrite URLs that would map to physical files, eg. `test.php` is a physical file on the filesystem then add an additional condition to check for the existence of this file before rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)\.php$ index.php?do=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sir, I try it, but not working, I have `http://example.com/test.php` file. when i placed your code on `.htaccess` and i browse `http://example.com/index.php?do=test` then it not working. after browsing its showing me homepage.

Comment: please reply, w3dk sir.

Comment: You presumably "browse" `/test.php`rather than `/index.php?do=test` - don't you? If `/index.php?do=test` does not work then that would seem to be down to your server-side script - is it not?